Is it possible to define multidimensional arrays from user input in C?
Is it possible to define multidimensional arrays from user input in C where the user could specify the number of dimensions, eg:
1 => arr[x]

2 => arr[x][x]

3 => arr[x][x][x]

(c noob)
I dont see how this could be written without hardcoding, since working with the array would require passing it as a pointer to a pointer for every dimension.

No. But you can have a (dynamically allocated) 1d array and calculate the 1d index based on the dimensions given in the input.

Suppose you could make such an array based on the user's input. What practical problem do you hope to solve, using such an array, when you don't know ahead of time (i.e., when you're writing the code) how many dimensions it has?

If you have an array with dynamic number of dimensions, you could access it by writing functions that take a variable number of indexes, probably by putting the dynamic indexes in an array.

@Chameleonballs Yes it is possible to allocated memory for a dynamic multidimensional array.  How do you want to use it?  Post the actions you would like to operate on it and what problem you are trying to solve - else this is too broad.

MUCH better dupe:  Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays

If the number of dimensions is bounded by a small integer (i.e. 4) then the answer is YES.

The answer to your question is "yes." It usually is when asking "is X possible?"
Here's a first go at implementing it using a single dimensional dynamically allocated array, and then a bunch of math to get positions within it as though it actually is mult-dimensional. Dimensions and indices are hard-coded, but those arrays could be dynamically generated at runtime.
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct multi_dim_array {
    size_t ndimensions;
    size_t *dimensions;
    int *data;
};

struct multi_dim_array *make_multi_dim_array(size_t n, size_t *dims) {
    if (n <= 0) return NULL;

    struct multi_dim_array *arr = malloc(sizeof(*arr));
    if (!arr) {
        return NULL;
    }

    arr->ndimensions = n;
    arr->dimensions = malloc(sizeof(size_t *) * n);
    if (!arr->dimensions) {
        free(arr);
        return NULL;
    }

    size_t total_size = 1;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (dims[i] <= 0) {
            free(arr->dimensions);
            free(arr); 
            return NULL;
        }

        total_size *= dims[i];
        arr->dimensions[i] = dims[i];
    }

    arr->data = malloc(sizeof(int) * total_size);
    if (!arr->data) {
        free(arr->dimensions);
        free(arr);
        return NULL;
    }

    return arr;
}

void set_multi_dim_array(struct multi_dim_array *arr, size_t *indices, int value) {
    size_t offset = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < arr->ndimensions; i++) {
        size_t sz = 1;
        for (size_t j = i + 1; j < arr->ndimensions; j++) {
            sz *= arr->dimensions[j];
        }

        offset += indices[i] * sz;
    }

    arr->data[offset] = value;
}

int get_multi_dim_array(struct multi_dim_array *arr, size_t *indices) {
    size_t offset = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < arr->ndimensions; i++) {
        size_t sz = 1;  
        for (size_t j = i + 1; j < arr->ndimensions; j++) {
            sz *= arr->dimensions[j];
        }
        
        offset += indices[i] * sz;
    }
    
    return arr->data[offset];
}

int main(void) {
    size_t dims[] = {2, 4, 3};
    size_t idxs[] = {1, 2, 1};

    struct multi_dim_array *arr = make_multi_dim_array(3, dims);

    set_multi_dim_array(arr, idxs, 42);
    printf("%d\n", get_multi_dim_array(arr, idxs));
}

But that's a lot of work, and you'd really want to read up on the XY problem to see if maybe you have one of those.
